# My iframe will simply not center

Tags: html, css, iframe

I've tried using a div to center the iframe, doesn't work. I've been through about 20 different posts and none have worked.

Here is the code:

```css
center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <iframe src="gallery.html" width="100%" style="height:100vh";></iframe>
</center>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Cool, glad it works for you. So could you please mark my answer as accepted for this question? :)

Comment: Done :) Just a quick question. It works perfect on desktop, but on mobile the iframe section is really tall and uses up alot of useless space. Im guessing its because the 100vh. But when i set it to % its really small.

Comment: When I changed to % units, it still takes up the same height. But if you want to reduce its height on mobile, use media queries and set a specific size you want for smaller screen sizes. Here take a look at this snippet, hope it helps https://jsfiddle.net/0jxpb5rs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this solution is what you want.

Reduce the size of the `iframe`, set `width` and `text-align` to the container element.

```css
.centered {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <iframe src="gallery.html" width="80%" style="height:100vh";></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: This helped a bit, it moves it slightly to the right. But instead of being 1/2 way, its about 1/5 way

Answer (score 1):

i guess you should try centering your iframe with flexbox.

```
.flex-wrap {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

<div class="flex-wrap">
    <div>
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com" width="120" style="height:100vh";></iframe>
    </div>
<div>
```

Comment: This centred it, but it is tiny. so tiny infact it cant even display anything

Answer (score -1):

center tag is already a centered position, you don't need to enter css.

Simply try this, it may help you.

```
<center><iframe src="https://www.google.com" width="120" style="height:100vh";></iframe></center>
```

Comment: No, the center tag has been deprecated for a few years, you have to use css

Comment: Its depreciated but you can use it, or if you want to use it in css then
.center{
text-align:center;}
It will be work for you.